# derivative curve formula

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, curves

> Let $r:I \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a continious differentiable curve.
>   Prove the following formula
>   $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{r(t)}{\Vert r \Vert})=\frac{c\times r}{\Vert r \Vert^3}$ where $c:=r \times \dot r$

Just "calculating" the derivative I get the following:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{r(t)}{\Vert r \Vert})=\frac{\dot r(t)}{\Vert r \Vert}-\frac{r(t)}{\Vert r \Vert^3}(r\cdot \dot r)\; \; \;$ where $\times$ is the cross product and $\cdot$ the scalar multiplication

I would appreciate some help/tips because I dont know how to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $$c\times r=(r\times \dot r)\times r=(r.r)\dot r-(\dot r.r)r$$

Comment: Very neat formula. Didnt know this one.

Comment: @XPenguen you can search for "triple vector product"